# Querying post.next in a given category

Tags: jekyll

When iterating through posts in a given category, with `{% for post in site.categories.CATEGORY %}`, `post.next` returns the next post in reverse chronological order. Is there any way to query the `post.next` in the specific category, rather than in general?

Comment: this looks like it has your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145061/get-next-and-previous-elements-out-of-an-array-in-liquid?rq=1

Comment: They use a different approach, I was thinking you could try to capture or assign all the posts from that cat to a temp variable and then loop thru them. Then maybe tempvariable.next would work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing exactly as Ron mentioned, just iterated through site.categories capturing each one, and then iterating the posts in that category.